# C# Google Chart JSON, Not enough columns given to draw the requested chart

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, google-visualization

I'm trying to get Google Charts working with data from a DataContext (db).
With this code:

```
public JsonResult getYearChart(clientId)
{
    DataDataContext db = new DataDataContext();

    var alldata = (from deba in db.debViews
                   where deba.ClientID == clientId
                   group deba by deba.Date.Value.Month 
                   into grp
                   select new
                       {
                           Month = grp.Key,
                           Price = grp.Sum(x => x.Price)
                       }).ToList();

    var cols = new[] { new { Month ="Month", Price ="Total" } };

    var ret = new[]
        {
            new { data = cols.Select(x => new string[] { x.Month, x.Price }) },
            new { data = alldata.Select(x => new string[] { x.Month.ToString(), Convert.ToString(x.Price) }) }
        };
```

And returning ret with Json.
This doesn't work, it just gives me "Not enough columns given to draw the requested chart". what would be the best practice to make a google chart dynamic with data from a DataContext?

This is the JavaScript I use to draw the chart with the Json response.

```
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    $.post('Ex/getYearChart', {},
function (data) {
    var tdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    var rows = data.length;
    var cols = data[0].length;

    tdata.addColumn('string', data[0][0]);
    for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        tdata.addColumn('number', data[0][i]);
    }

    tdata.addRows(data.length);
    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        tdata.setCell(i, 0, data[i][0]);
        for (var j = 1; j < cols; j++) {
            var value = parseInt(data[i][j]);
            tdata.setCell(i, j, value);

        }
    }

    var options = {
        title: 'Test Chart',
        isStacked: true,
        width: 500,
        height: 400,
        vAxis: { title: "More Text" },
        hAxis: { title: "Date" }
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(tdata, options);

}
    )}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly "doesn't work"?

Comment: Please edit the question, and change the title to better describe your problem. "C# Google Chart JSON" is not a description of a problem, and your tags already mention the related topics/technologies.

Comment: Changed the title and edited the text.

Comment: Update your question with an example of the contents of `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Until you give an example of the contents of `data`, I can't say what the problem is for certain, but I know that this will cause problems for you, even absent problems with `data`:

```
tdata.addColumn('string', data[0][0]);
for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    tdata.addColumn('number', data[0][i]);
}
```

You should start incrementing `i` from `1` instead of `0`, since you are already adding a column for the first element in each row.